# Google Identity Platform multi tenancy login

Tags: multi-tenant, google-identity

I've started a new project with google identity platform, is it possible somehow to have a common login page without knowing the tenant id? from the docs I don't see anything about this, the idea is to give the possibility to the final user to login from a normal page and then redirect him to the right tenant. I know that logically could be wrong, but a lot of service do something like this (jira is one of them) if this is not possible using the service I was thinking to add a table to my db with:

```
sha256(email)|tenant
```

so when the user insert email/password I fetch the tenant, and then proceed with the authentication. Do you have any advice?

many thanks

Comment: i think my question is also related. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960293/assign-project-level-user-to-multiple-tenants

the only way i know how to login at the tenant level is by knowing the tenant id. the follow on question is how to manage a project-level login that can access multiple tenants

Comment: in my case the app use a single db for all the tenants, I have 2 tables organizations and users, in the first one I have an internal uuid and the tenant id while in the second I have the sha256 of the user's email. Before send the request for login I send a request to find the tenant id, once I get the response I attach the tenant id to the login request...I'm still not sure if this is the right approach

Comment: here's what we're currently doing in our project: we use subdomain urls to know which tenant the user is trying to login to. we make an api call to get the tenant id for the particular subdomain when the user first loads the subdomain login page. once we have the tenant id we set the tenantId on the firebase auth instance on the frontend. this scopes the auth instance to that particular tenant. then we can login the user once they click the login button. javascript example:  auth.tenantId = tenantId; auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)

Comment: i think some of the google products don't provide enough documentation details on the "right approach". but your method sounds fine also!

Comment: yeah that was one options but I wanted to let user login from a single page instead of different sub domains, but everything is still in progress so we could change it later

Comment: @francesco.venica were you able to find a solution that does not involve creating subdomains?

Comment: Instead of using the subdomain could you show an identifier-first (email) login flow? You take the users email address and use its domain to lookup the tenant, as per the example above.