# Assign project-level user to multiple tenants

Tags: multi-tenant, google-identity

Cannot find anywhere on Google Identity Platform docs that clearly describe whether it's possible to assign a single user to multiple tenants. see https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-managing-tenants

My project needs the capability to have a single user be able to login to multiple, separate tenants. Currently, I have to create a new user on every tenant I want to be able to login to. This is not good because each new user I create has a different uid and separate password management. For a single user, I want to be able to maintain the same uid across tenants so the associated user data can be consistent as well.

I was thinking there would be some way to create a user at the project level (not tenant level) and then assign that user to specific tenants?

Some random thoughts: The docs say some things about migrating users between tenants, perhaps that is one way. Also was thinking that creating a tenant user with my existing project-level uid would somehow merge them so the uid and password management is the same?

---

Edit: I found this conceptual discussion to be helpful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/403274/multitenancy-with-cross-tenant-users
what I gathered from that link is that SSO is separate from multi-tenancy. So I'm trying to figure out an SSO solution on top of multi-tenancy google idp. Any code solutions/suggestions for how to add SSO on top of multi-tenant google identity platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the same user across tenants maybe you should instead rely on the user email, custom claims, federated ID (eg. `user.providerData[0].uid`). When you get an ID token for the user you have access to this same information regardless of the tenant or `user.uid`.